Unable to locate element by ID but can locate using XPath
I am using Selenium and Chrome browser in macOS to test my code where I am entering some data in a webpages to retrieve data. I'm facing one issue where when I try to search for an element with ID, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Developer/PYTHON/SELENIUM/linkedInScrape.py", line 29, in <module>
    jobQuery = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
  File "/Users/siddhu/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

However if I try to access the element with XPath, the compilation is successful. The code for searching with XPath is:
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/")
jobQuery = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
                                                                  "//input[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword')]")))

The code for searching with ID is:
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/")
jobQuery = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember922"))

Is there a mistake from my side in locating the elements?

The XPath code will return an element whose ID begins with jobs-search-box-keyword, but the search by ID is looking for a specific number at the end of the ID. Maybe that ID doesn't exist.

Your XPath is correct. It seems like LinkedIn wants you first to Sign in .
Did your code handle signing in to LinkedIn ?

Yes ! Ive handled the sign-in but didnt include that code over here .

When you used the CSS selector to specify the ID, you are specifying the exact ID which includes a number that seems to be dynamic.
input#jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember922
                                      ^^^ this number changes

Your XPath doesn't contain the number so it seems to be fine.
Another option I found is to use some other attributes in a CSS selector that remain constant.
input:not([disabled])[aria-label='Search by title, skill, or company']

